# Are there online tools to solve card-based puzzles?

Tags: recommendations

There are "chess board editor" sites, which you can use to solve chess puzzles. Input chess position and move the pieces trying different combinations of moves. For example: http://www.caissa.com/chess-tools/pgn-editor.php

Is there the same thing for puzzles, which are based on card games? That means a tool, which would be more or less equivalent to physical card deck.
I need for [Preferans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferans), but may be [Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_bridge)-site or any other tricks-based game will be fine too.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not asking for something that actually "solves" puzzles, you're just looking for an on-line tool that lets you simulate playing out hands etc?  For, like, reviewing situations and/or trying out new strategies?

Comment: Yes. The tool, which would be more or less equivalent to physical cards.

Comment: It's not the answert yet, but I'm developing cardforest.com as a place you can create and play card games. I think what you need is just a simplified version of a such game. PS, I'm considering making it open source and I'm looking for core developers

Comment: I am removing the tag [trick-taking-games] per [this meta thread](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1585/3389). Unfortunately, I need to add a tag back in and [recommendations] is the one that seems the most apt. So I'm voting to close this as a recommendation question.

Answer (score 2):

[Tabletop Simulator](http://store.steampowered.com/app/286160/) gives you a sandbox board game world, so you could use it to solve card puzzles. However, it is not free.

For a free version you can try using [this](http://humage.com/playing_cards.html) website. It doesn't have the best user experience, but it does the trick.